# Updating Fields - Realm

Tags: ios, sql, swift, notifications, realm

In the below class Individual field values will be available at different times(Multiple Local Notification) through out any date. So I am planning to update the each Realm objects multiple times when Local notification is handled by user.

```
class DailyStatus:Object {
dynamic var date = ""
dynamic var statusMA = ""
dynamic var roundsChanted = 0
dynamic var statusDA = ""
dynamic var statusSB = ""
dynamic var bookReading = ""

var todayDate: String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "date"
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    date = todayDate
}

}
```

Don't know how can I update individual var of Realm Object using the Primary key multiple times. Need help on Realm Queries.

Comment: Are you actually using an RLMObject (as opposed to an Object) because you're mixing Swift and Objective-C, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Can you not just retrieve the object by primary key and update whatever property based on each local notification?

Comment: @AdamFish could you provide some code sample.

Comment: @caseynolan u r right!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object has a primary key you can always retrieve it via that key and simply update the specific property. For example:

```
try! Realm().write { 
    var status = Realm().objectForPrimaryKey(aKey) 
    status.statusDA = "NEW TEXT"
}
```